# Utility to zip(archive) a solution?

Tags: visual-studio, zip, solution

Anyone know of a utility that exists which can traverse a solution file (.sln) and all of its project files and create a zip (archive) of that? My google-fu is failing me on this one, there are too many results showing how to write a program to zip files.

Answer (score 3):

If you have 7zip installed, you can create a batch file to do what you want.

Create a file called `archive.bat` in the solution directory, open it and add:

```
"c:\program files\7-zip\7z.exe" a -tzip archive.zip * -xr@archive.ignored
```

Then create a text file called `archive.ignored` (in the same location as the .bat file) that lists the filenames/wildcards to be excluded from your archive.zip. For example:

```
obj
debug
bin
packages
*.obj
*.dll
*.exe
*.zip
*.suo
.vs
archive.ignored
archive.bat
```

Comment: This sounds like a directory based solution, while useful, I'm looking for something that will specifically traverse the sln and proj files and only include the files that those files reference.

Answer (score 1):

[CleanProject](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bca632e0-3948-43c8-b337-da47275717b6) almost does what I want, but it doesn't actually read the .sln file so you need to have the relevant projects in the solution folder, and this grabs everything in those folders (cleaning up somethings you wouldn't want in the zip), whether they are referenced in the solution or not.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish that by creating a [WinZip job](http://kb.winzip.com/help/help_jobsusingwizard.htm).  It's a one time setup where you define what, where, and when to create a zip file.  I've used it to automate some backup tasks.

Comment: This sounds like a directory based solution, I'm looking for something that will traverse the sln and proj files and only include the files those files reference.

Comment: That's somewhat correct.  But, you can set up the job to include/exclude specific file types within folders.

Comment: Right, but I only want to include the files that are directly referenced in the .sln and .csproj/.vbproj files.